# How to install ffi 1.9.25 successfully on M1 Chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apple-m1

```
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.9.25), and Bundler cannot continue.

In Gemfile:
  bootstrap-sass was resolved to 3.3.7, which depends on
    sass was resolved to 3.7.4, which depends on
      sass-listen was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
        rb-inotify was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
          ffi
```

I'm running into this issue on an M1 laptop for a rails project I'm running `bundle install`, how to resolve this?

I tried running

> gem install ffi -v '1.9.25' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

Which installed the gem successfully, but when I try to run `rake db:migrate` this error comes up

```
rake db:migrate                                                                                                                
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/kanye.west/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace (_ffi_prep_closure) - /Users/kanye.west/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/Users/kanye.west/dev/anenta/config/application.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kanye.west/dev/anenta/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/Users/kanye.west/dev/anenta/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kanye.west/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/kanye.west/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: can you try **gem install ffi -v '1.9.25' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"**. see if this works. Also please share entire error log if this solution doesn't work

Comment: that worked! what does that flag do?

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. I've added answer, request you to please approve. Regarding the flag Essentially, the flag instructs the compiler to disregard instances of implicit function declaration rather than throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Install ffi gem with below command

```
gem install ffi -v '1.9.25' -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Comment: unfortunately this allows installing the gem but fails to run anythign substantial

Comment: can you elaborate?? what issue are we facing here?